# Racket Mode not working, although all requirements has been provided

Tags: package-repositories

I wanna do some Scheme. For this, I choose Racket language. And I'm Emacs user about 1-2 months.
So I think I did all requirements for writing Racket in Emacs. But still, I can't get `racket-mode` package in list of all packages in Emacs.
So firstly, I installed Racket to my computer. It's okay and I can write Racket in `repl mode`(but I want `racket-mode`).
After all, I know that I need Melpa for installing packages. But I can't find `racket-mode` in `list-of-packages`. This is image of packages I have.

[image]

So what's problem. Why I can't find `racket-mode` package

**Some Points:**
I write this code into `init` file and I have `init` file in `.emacs.d` directory

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
```

Don't recomment DrRacket I only use Emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no racket-mode package in MELPA Stable, so it's not listed in the package list. You'll have to add regular MELPA instead and refresh the package archives.